# Using .htaccess and GeoipLite Legacy + mod_geoip

Tags: apache, .htaccess, geoip

I have flat site (html + css) sitting on a LAMP stack server which also hosts other sites.

I use mod_geoip combined with legacy GeoLite City downloaded database.

I need to get a users region to repoint them to their localised version.

The following Apache variables are available on every page load even on sites which do not require a GeoIP lookup.

- GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE
- GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME
- GEOIP_REGION
- GEOIP_CITY
- GEOIP_DMA_CODE
- GEOIP_AREA_CODE
- GEOIP_LATITUDE
- GEOIP_LONGITUDE

Below is my geoip.conf module file.

```
    <IfModule mod_geoip.c>
      GeoIPEnable On
      GeoIPDBFile /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
    </IfModule>
```

The geoip check is only required in the root .htaccess on one of my sites. As this site is flat I cannot use a dynamic language to call the geoip check.

How ca I remove this unnecessary server load?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `GeoIPEnable` to `Off` in your `geoip.conf` file and only enable it in the relevant `Location` or `Directory` block. If you have `AllowOverride AuthConfig` set, you will also be able to set it directly in your .htaccess file.